# Research on improving long term focus

Tags: behavior, concentration, goals

I have seen a lot of research on concentration or focus in the short term. But what about concentration and focus in the long term? For example, if I set a goal to write a novel over the course of 4 years, what factors go into predicting my ability, willingness, and interest in finishing that novel?

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE.  I am sorry but this question could be closed for being off-topic.  Although the subject may be on topic, there are no references to research you have carried out and where your assumptions come from on how "predicting my ability, willingness, and interest" affects concentration and focus in the long term.  Can you please provide some references to the research you mentioned and how you believe ability, willingness and interest affects things? (cont...)

Comment: (...cont) You may want to have a look at the [tour page](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/tour) for this stack, and our [good question guide](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for guidance on how to improve the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duckworth's [research on] [grit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grit_(personality_trait)) would probably qualify; she defined grit as perseverance/persistance combined with passion...

However as grit is currently measured, [grit doesn't seem](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/27845531) all that different from [conscientiousness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conscientiousness), which is a much more established measure. Duckworth herself admits we should probably go back to drawing board for measuring passion; see her [closing remarks](https://www.npr.org/sections/ed/2016/05/25/479172868/angela-duckworth-responds-to-a-new-critique-of-grit) on NPR:

> She said she's currently thinking about revising her "grit scale," her basic experimental tool, specifically the questions about passion.